# Add metadata to activity in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin

How can I add the MetaData for searchable xml to an Activity using attributes in Xamarain.Android.
Metadata that has to be added :-

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable">
</meta-data>
```

Here I am making a android searchable Listview using ActionBar search Widget in Xamarin.Android.
any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a MetaDataAttribute that you can add to your Activity.

```
[Activity]
[MetaData("android.app.searchable", Resource="@xml/searchable")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add both IntentFilterAttribute and MetaDataAttribute

Following solution works fine for me:

```
[Activity (...)]
[IntentFilter(new[]{Intent.ActionSearch})]
[MetaData("android.app.searchable", Resource="@xml/searchable")]

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
```

...
}

Good explanation how to add search functionality can be found here:
http://codetheory.in/adding-search-to-android/